# Перемена первого и последнего элемента

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Нужно поменять местами первый и последний положительный элементы (указатели).

Язык Си. Никаких malloc() sizeof() и других функций (курс только начался). Задание нужно реализовать, максимально используя указатели. Работаю в Turbo C++ 3.1, так как другие компиляторы выдают ошибку при присваивании указателям значения 0. Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
/*В заданном одномерном массиве поменять местами первый и последний положительные элементы */
void main()
{
    int a[3];
    int *i, *perv, *posl, t;
    *perv = 0;
    *posl = 0;

    for (i = a; i < a + 3; i++) {
        scanf("%d", i);
        if (*i > 0) {
            *posl = *i;          // находим последний положительный элемент
            t = *posl;
        }
    }

    for (i = a; i < a + 3; i++) {
        if (*i > 0) {
            *perv = *i;          // находим первый положительный элемент
            *posl = *perv;
            *perv = t;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%dn", *perv);
    printf("%dn", *posl);
    printf("n");
    for (i = a; i < a + 3; i++)
        printf("%d", *i);
    getch();
}
```

На вход: 1 2 3 на выходе будет: 3 1 и 1 2 3. То есть `*perv` и `*posl` местами поменялись, но когда дело доходит до распечатки массива, то ничего не изменяется. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Подумайте хорошенько, что означает выражение

`*perv = *i;`

Comment: Значение i "пихаем" в указатель

Comment: Указатель *perv = 0; я инициализировал нулем, чтобы в нем хоть что-то было.

Comment: А вот и нет. Значение по адресу i тут пихается в память по адресу perv, т.е. в 0, т.е. никуда. На некоторых ОС это вообще должно свалить программу.

Надо просто

    perv = i;

Comment: Еще раз хорошенько разберитесь с указателями, с их природой и как с ними работать, особенно с разъыменованием указателей.

Comment: Выражение *perv = 0 (например) говорит: "Присвоить значение 0 по адресу, содержащемуся в perv". Поэтому для обнуления самого указателся пишем просто perv = 0

Comment: И действительно, спасибо за помощь, я вам очень благодарен =)

Comment: Я думал наоборот, perv=0 - это какая-то билиберда, ибо указатель не может содержать адрес 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Продолжение комментариев.

Указатель как переменная может содержать все, что угодно. Другое дело, как это будет разыменовывать. Если адрес несуществующий или требуемые операции по нему запрещены, то программа вылетит.

0 - особое значение. Может нести определенную информационную нагрузку при передачи в функции. Но чтение-запись по нему, скорее всего, выдаст ошибку времени исполнения.

Comment: Когда я объявил указатель int *perv, то в памяти не выделился для него адрес, и когда я захотел поместить туда какое-то значение, то это значение шло в никуда? Я правильно понял? (без *perv=0 )

Comment: При объявлении указателя никакой памяти не выделяется. Для этого нужны специальные процедуры. Указатель сам по себе просто содежит некоторый адрес и больше ничего.

Comment: Да, памяти не выделяется... Значит самое главное - это запомнить, что перед тем как вставлять в указатель какое-то значение, то ему нужно сначала присвоить адрес. Так, да?

Comment: Ну, это должен быть какой-то реальный адрес, по которому можно что-то делать - читать или писать, по контексту. Например, адрес переменной или адрес массива. Можно присвоить вообще любое значение. Указатель - это просто целочисленная переменная, как правило, типа unsigned long. Поэтому может в ней содержаться все, что угодно. Другое дело - что случится, когда будет произведено обращение по этому значению.

Comment: Можно присвоить вообще любое значение
Попробовал perv = 6 и все по-прежнему хорошо. Вот этого я не знал, спасибо =)